# How to make a conditional statement continue to rest if the code?

Tags: javascript

How to get this conditional to continue, to the next part of the code. I managed to do it by putting a console.log but still I thing three is a cleaner solution.

```js
// condition
if (conditionA === conditionB || conditionA === '') {
      if (link.closest('.somothing')) { /*go to the rest of the code*/ } else { return }
  }    
// Flow Rest of the code ......
```

Comment: If the conditional is empty, it would continue to rest of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### synchronous execution

Write a function with your "next part of your code" and call it.

Link: [Javascript Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)

```
// condition
if (conditionA === conditionB || conditionA === '') {
   if (link.closest('.somothing')) { 
      /*go to the rest of the code*/
      nextCode();
   } else {
      return 
   }
}    
// Flow Rest of the code ......

function nextCode() {
   console.log("call this");
}
```

##### asynchronous execution

Another approach if you have async sourcecode that helps you to keep your code clean.

Link:[Javascript Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
new Promise((resolve) => {
   console.log("execute 1");
   // condition
   if (conditionA === conditionB || conditionA === '') {
      if (link.closest('.somothing')) {
         /*go to the rest of the code*/
         console.log("execute 2");
      } else { 
         return 
      }
   }    
}).then(() => {
   console.log("execute 3");    
});
// Flow Rest of the code ......
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reverse the condition and return early.

```
if (conditionA === conditionB || conditionA === '') {
    if (!link.closest('.somothing')) return;
}
```

Comment: problem is I want it the exact way it is now reverse won't work from me :(.